# Javascript else if statement not working with form validation

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I'm trying to validate a form that will send an email. At the moment the button returns formCheck() onclick. Which is meant to display a popup respective of field completetion.

I'm new to JS so I'm having a little trouble working out what I'm doing wrong as the outcome is always the else "Thanks".

```
   <script>
        function formCheck() {
            if (document.getElementById("Name") === "")
            {
                alert("please enter name");
            }
            else if (document.getElementById("Email") === "")
            {
                alert("Please enter an email address");
            }
            else if (document.getElementById("Name") && document.getElementById("Email") === "")
            {
                alert("Please enter a Name and Email address");
            }
            else {
                alert("Thanks");
            }
        }
    </script>
```

To me it looks like I'm either not using an if statementcorrectly or its not picking up the fields are empty when defined as "". If anybody can point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be comparing the value instead of the object itself:

```
document.getElementById("Name").value
```

Comment: `===` is also fine as both are strings.

Comment: Ohh I see. I need to compare what is inside Name and not the Name itself. My bad! Thanks for pointing that out.